# Open PDF using cell value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'd like to open a specific PDF based on the file path in another sheet "Paths" cell C2, when I click a button (in another sheet) with a macro assigned.

I've just started learning vba last month so far I have this but I encounter an error -

```
Sub Sample()

    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Sheets("Paths").Range("C2")

End Sub
```

The error is:

Run-time error '-214722104 (800401ea)':
Cannot open the specified file.

Please help.

Comment: What exactly is the content of `C2`?

Comment: Hi! it contains the file path to my pdf: ‪C:\Users\Renee Arianne\Desktop\Desktop - Filled CIS\CIS_2016 v5 filled.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I just made this roundabout way to open the pdf ...

'''
Sub OpenCIS()

```
Sheets("Paths").Select
Range("C3").Select
Selection.Copy

Dim x As Variant
Dim Path As String

' Set the Path variable equal to the path of your program's installation
Path = Sheets("Paths").Range("C2")

x = Shell(Path, vbNormalFocus)

Application.Wait Now + 0.00002
Application.SendKeys "^{o}", True

Application.Wait Now + 0.00002
Application.SendKeys "^{v}", True
Application.SendKeys "{HOME}", True
Application.SendKeys "{DEL}", True 'deletes the ? that appears before the path
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
```

End Sub
'''
I don't know why the path appears as     ?C:\Users\Renee Arianne\Desktop\Desktop - Filled CIS\CIS_2016 v5 filled.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no error on the script.
please check below points.

1. Checking address of "sheets", "cells"
2. Checking value of "C2" (as expected, the most likely)
   "C2" value like this C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\KR01.pdf

please check it.

Comment: Hi yes the value of "C2" is ‪C:\Users\Renee Arianne\Desktop\Desktop - Filled CIS\CIS_2016 v5 filled.pdf

Comment: I noticed the problem is excel adds a ? to the path (?C:\Users\Renee Arianne\Desktop\Desktop - Filled CIS\CIS_2016 v5 filled.pdf), instead of just directly to c:/. Would you know how to eliminate this?